# Flutter - GetX - pass data to controller and process and return to view

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx, state-management

The view i have for my dashboard is here https://postimg.cc/PvjfLfWf. I want to pass a date from UI to controller and fetch orders for that date. Seperate them into delivered orders and others. After that i want to display length of delivered orders and ongoing orders. Also i want to display total amount of orders placed via COD. and display COD orders in summary widget.

I have written code in UI. But it's taking too much of time to load since it is a large database.
How to do this in GetX controller?

```
processOrders() {
    _db
        .collection('orders')
        .where('driverId', isEqualTo: sp.getString('uid'))
        .where(
        'timeStamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(pickedDate!))
        .where('timeStamp', isLessThan: Timestamp.fromDate(nextDay!))
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'Delivered')
        .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        deliveredOrders.add(element.data());
      });
    });

    var CODOrders = deliveredOrders.where((element) =>
    element['paid'] == 'COD').toList();
    CODOrders.forEach((element) {
      cashInHand = cashInHand + element['grandTotal'];
      tip = tip + element['tip'];
    });
  }
```

I'm new to GETX and flutter. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example if you want to display the "totalAmount"

declare variable  and assign the value in controller
**homeController.dart**

```
var totalAmount = 0.00.obs;

// assign data
totalAmount.value = 1000;
```

**home.dart**

```
  final homeController _homeController = Get.put(homeController());

// read data here like this
  Text(_homeController.totalAmount.value)
```

Comment: And i want to do all the above process in the controller itself and just pass the data to UI. That is what you are saying right?

Comment: yes , you have to follow the same process for all other data. thank you